# How to add event handler to a C# AvalonEdit Caret PositionChanged event in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalonedit

I have a data template defined in xaml as:

```
<DataTemplate>
<avalonEdit:TextEditor 
    Name="xmlEditor"
    SyntaxHighlighting="XML"
    FontFamily="Consolas"
    FontSize="10pt"
/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I need to add an ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.TextEditor.TextArea.Caret.PositionChanged event to this. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access this in your xaml you have to set this in your code behind.

You can do this like this:

```
AvalonTextEditorControl.TextArea.Caret.PositionChanged += new EventHandler(
    (sender, args) => {
         // do some stuff
    }
);
```

Or with a seperate event function instead, when you prefer it:

```
AvalonTextEditorControl.TextArea.Caret.PositionChanged += TextEditorCaret_PositionChanged;

private void TextEditorCaret_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

---

**Update**

If you want to use it in you XAML maybe because of your DataTemplate. You must implement this on your own. I thing than you got two options:

1. Get the source from ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit on GitHub and modify the TextEditor class. Just add an EventHandler and call it in the TextArea.Caret.PositionChanged Event.
2. Create you own UserControl which inherits from the ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit TextEditor and add the EventHandler like in option 1.